# Storage account - The account being accessed does not support http

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I have created an MVC Web application application and a storage account(Table). I'm getting the error

```
StatusMessage:The account being accessed does not support http.
ErrorCode:AccountRequiresHttps
```

When I created an MVC application, I have ticked Configure for Https. Would anyone know where I can configure it to use https and why I'm not able to access it? (I tried running on both IIS express and IIS)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**
By default, an Azure Storage account requires secure access (that means access over HTTPS) by default.
The box you checked (Configure for HTTPS) means that the **MVC Web Application** is accessible via HTTPS (only). The error you're getting is that you are *accessing the Storage Account* over HTTP. So that's an outgoing connection to your storage account from your web application. This is **not** covered by the box you checked.

**Solution**
If you want to connect to the **Storage Account** using HTTPS, make sure the connection string you are using for the storage account contains/starts with `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;`. This configures the storage account client to access the storage account over HTTPS.

**Additional info**

> The secure transfer option enhances the security of your storage account by only allowing requests to the storage account by secure connection. For example, when calling REST APIs to access your storage accounts, you must connect using HTTPs. Any requests using HTTP will be rejected when 'secure transfer required' is enabled.

**EDIT:**
If you're using the constructor for the `CloudStorageAccount` class to 'build' the connectionstring, make sure to pass in `true` for the `useHttps` parameter.

Comment: I'm storing StorageAccount name , storage key, table name in the secrets.json file. Tried including DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https. I have 'secure transfer required' is enabled - Didn't made any difference.

Comment: But setting useHttps to true in  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount( new StorageCredentials(this.settings.StorageAccount, this.settings.StorageKey), true); worked. :) Thanks @rickvdbosch

Comment: @Dev for others landing on this question, please mark as answer if this solved your issue.